# Trigger view controller in a navigation controller from tab bar controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have an app that has a tab bar controller that houses 5 navigation controllers. Each nav controller has a menu as the first view controller however when the tab is selected I want to bypass the menu and go to the next view controller.

Flow:

TabBar Controller -> Nav Controller -> Menu -> View Controller 1 -> View Controller (level 2)

```
              -> Nav Controller -> Menu -> View Controller 2 -> View Controller (level 2)

              -> Nav Controller -> Menu -> View Controller 3 -> View Controller (level 2)

              -> Nav Controller -> Menu -> View Controller 4 -> View Controller (level 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the NSNotificationCenter to post notifications to your View Controllers when the Tab Bar gets tapped. To set up this mechanism you have to do this in your first view Controller.

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController ()<UITabBarControllerDelegate>

@end

@implementation FirstViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tabBarController.delegate = self;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if (((UINavigationController *)viewController).topViewController == self) {

        //Push the next view controller to skip the menu
        //Replace newViewController with the disired one
        UIViewController *newViewController = [UIViewController new];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:newViewController animated:NO];

        NSLog(@"Push view controller first tab");

    }else {
        //Post a notification to inform the other view Controller
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"tabBarControllerDidSelectViewController" object:((UINavigationController *)viewController)];
    }
}


@end
```

In your the rest of your view controllers do the following

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController ()

@end

@implementation SecondViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(didTabed:) name:@"tabBarControllerDidSelectViewController" object:nil];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.     }

-(void)didTabed:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if ([[notification object] isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {

        UIViewController *selectedViewController = ((UINavigationController *)[notification object]).topViewController;

        if (selectedViewController == self) {

            //Push the next view controller to skip the menu
            //Replace newViewController with the disired one
            UIViewController *newViewController = [UIViewController new];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:newViewController animated:NO];

            NSLog(@"Push view Controller tap2");
        }

   }
}

@end
```

If you have any questions about this please don't hesitate to ask!

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It has a problem as its not type view contorller but UINavigation controller. Have I missed something? I have edited my questions to show my storyboard flow. Thanks for all your help so far!

Comment: you are right. I have updated my answer. Unfortunately I found an other issue. This will just work after the first time changing the tabs. Because to register the observer the View needs to be loaded at least once. I will try to figure this out and let you know if I got a solution for this issue.